# Is it possible to gunzip multiple files to a specific directory without deleting the original gz files?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, gunzip

I know this can be done for single files, e.g.

> gunzip -c my.gz > somedir/my

Can it be done for multiple files?

[UPDATE]
I have a directory with a large number of .gz files (not .tar.gz), and I want to gunzip them into another directory while leaving the original files untouched.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try something like

```
for a in *.gz; do gunzip -c $a > somedir/`echo $a | sed s/.gz//`; done
```

Comment: Deleted my post.. Your one-liner is more simple :)

Comment: basename might be a little simpler: for a in *.gz; do zcat $a > somedir/`basename $a`; done

Comment: Thanks Neil, but basename $a doesn't work for me in bash on Mac as it appears above - perhaps some punctuation is missing?

Comment: Thanks Andrejs, Nifle, Neil. This command does the trick.

Comment: basename $a needed telling to remove the .gz. therefore: basename $a .gz

Comment: The basename option does not work

Answer (score 2):

This will work in bash

```
for FILE in *.gz
do
    echo -n "File $FILE... "
    gzip -c $FILE > ${FILE%.gz}
    echo "Done"
done
```

Building on Andreja's answer, adding correction for file names.

Comment: Forgot to add semicolons ;)

Comment: Sorry, where exactly do they go? :)

Comment: Uhmm.. after each command within a loop? :) echo; gzip; echo; done...

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the one before the first "do"! This works for me if I update to use gunzip and insert the target directory. More work needed to strip the ".gz" from the target uncompressed files. Thanks.

Comment: This extracts my text files from .gz files all garbled.

Answer (score 2):

This also works.  Just another way of doing it.  It will not garble up your extracted text files.  I have actually tested this.

```
for f in *.gz; do
  STEM=$(basename "${f}" .gz)
  gunzip -c "${f}" > /somedir/"${STEM}";
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each file has a name like

```
foo.bar.gz
```

`basename` (GNU coreutils 8.4) can give you the original uncompressed file's name, thus I'd do

```
for f in /source/dir/*.gz; do t=$(basename $f .gz); gunzip -c $f > /target/dir/$t; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like job for a quick perl/python/ruby/etc. script.

Just adjust the code in this [example](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/sysadmin/ch02_03.htm) to apply the necessary gunzip command.

Answer (score 0):

This version preserves the original filetimes as inplace gzip does, and is "space-safe":

```
IFS=$'\n';for a in *.gz; do d=`basename $a .gz`;echo gunzip -c $a > somedir/$d; touch somedir/$d -r $a; done;
```

I found quoting "$a" and "$d" thus, was unnecessary as bash appeared to automatically escape spaces.